# error en el comando "npm run build"

Tags: webpack, línea-de-comandos

Tengo un problema al ejecutar el comando `npm run build`, el codigo que se muestra abajo es la configucacion que uso en el archivo webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
    
        mode: 'development',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.html$/i,
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options:{
                        attributes: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: './src/index.html',
                filename: './index.html'
            })
        ]
    
    }
```

El error que me sale es este:

```
C:\Users\kevin\Documents\WWW\JAVASCRIPT\06-webpack>npm run build

> 06-webpack@1.0.0 build C:\Users\kevin\Documents\WWW\JAVASCRIPT\06-webpack
> webpack

asset main.js 4.39 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main) asset ./index.html 2.39 KiB [compared for emit] runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules cacheable modules 304 bytes   ./src/index.js 96 bytes [built] [code generated]   ./src/js/componentes.js 208 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js):   ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
   - options has an unknown property 'attributes'. These properties are valid:
     object { preprocessor?, sources?, minimize?, esModule? }

  - validate.js:104 validate
    [06-webpack]/[schema-utils]/dist/validate.js:104:11

  - NormalModule.js:502 Object.getOptions
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:502:19

  - index.js:17 Object.loader
    [06-webpack]/[html-loader]/dist/index.js:17:27

  - ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js):

  - ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

  - - options has an unknown property 'attributes'. These properties are valid:

  - object { preprocessor?, sources?, minimize?, esModule? }

  - validate.js:104 validate
    [06-webpack]/[schema-utils]/dist/validate.js:104:11

  - NormalModule.js:502 Object.getOptions
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:502:19

  - index.js:17 Object.loader
    [06-webpack]/[html-loader]/dist/index.js:17:27

  - NormalModule.js:676 processResult
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:676:19

  - NormalModule.js:778
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:778:5

  - LoaderRunner.js:399
    [06-webpack]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11

  - LoaderRunner.js:251
    [06-webpack]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18

  - child-compiler.js:169
    [06-webpack]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18

  - Compiler.js:534
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:534:11

  - Compiler.js:1089
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1089:17


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [06-webpack]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14

  - Compiler.js:1085
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1085:33

  - Compilation.js:2526
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2526:11


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [06-webpack]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14

  - Compilation.js:2519
    [06-webpack]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2519:38



1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details) webpack 5.36.1 compiled with 2 errors in 1270 ms npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! 06-webpack@1.0.0 build: `webpack` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the 06-webpack@1.0.0 build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-30T03_55_16_881Z-debug.log
```

Alguien sería tan amable de indicarme porque sale ese error. De antemano muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, por si a alguien le sirve, después de la version @1.0.0 la configuración del archvo webpack.config era de esta manera:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options:{
                attributes: false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

pero en la versión que yo tengo `(@2.1.2)` la configuración ahora es así:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options:{
                sources: false,
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

lo que cambió fué la propiedad de "attributes" porque ahora se debe colocar "sources".

Espero a alguien le sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Marca tu respuesta como correcta, para que la pregunta quede "cerrada" y ayude a demas personas con problemas similares a identificar la solucion

Comment: Gracias me sirvió de ayuda tu respuesta.